# TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings NodeJS

Tags: node.js, path, arguments, typeerror

I'm creating a simple web API using NodeJS express, for some home domotics. For my TV I'm using the following library --> https://github.com/hobbyquaker/lgtv2.

When I run my code locally, for example;

```
        var lgtv = require('lgtv2')({
        url: 'ws://192.168.178.31:3000'
    });

    lgtv.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    lgtv.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('connected');
        lgtv.request('ssap://system/turnOff', function(err, res) {
            lgtv.disconnect();
        });

    });
```

It run's fine. However, the same code, deployed to my Synology NAS, results in an error.

```
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
at path.js:360:15
at Array.filter (native)
at exports.join (path.js:358:36)
at module.exports (/volume1/web/NodeJS/node_modules/persist-path/index.js:19:22)
at new LGTV (/volume1/web/NodeJS/node_modules/lgtv2/index.js:47:16)
at LGTV (/volume1/web/NodeJS/node_modules/lgtv2/index.js:38:16)
at Object.module.exports.setNetflix (/volume1/web/NodeJS/controllers/tv.js:50:36)
at /volume1/web/NodeJS/routes/routes.js:43:12
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/volume1/web/NodeJS/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/volume1/web/NodeJS/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
```

The only actual difference I can spot is the NPM version, which is v10.14.1 locally and v0.10.48 on my NAS. Is there any way to bypass this problem and get this working?

Randy

Comment: My first suggestion would be to accurately test your code using the same versions that you will be using in production....i.e. the same versions that you have on your NAS.  My second thought would be to upgrade the versions that you have on your NAS to reflect your development environment.   Also in my opinion the version difference is huge between the npm versions.

Answer (score 1):

It is very strange library.

Try this code

```
console.log('Platform = ',process.platform);
var lgtv = require('lgtv2')({
    url: 'ws://192.168.178.31:3000',
    clientKey: ''
});

lgtv.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

lgtv.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected');
    lgtv.request('ssap://system/turnOff', function(err, res) {
        lgtv.disconnect();
    });

});
```